# Prawn: Multiple tables side-by-side, each table spanning multiple pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I am realizing a 3-column layout. There are 3 independent tables, one in each column, and they span multiple pages. When, for example, the first table reaches the end of its column, it **should not** proceed in the next column, but proceed on the next page in "its" column, i.e. the first column. Same for the other tables.
My problem: When one table starts a new page, the other tables (positioned with bounding_box) will follow on this new created page, not on the page where the preceeding table started.

The desired layout is like this:

```
Page 1:
T-1 T-2 T-3
111 222 333
111 222 333
Page 2:
T-1 T-2 T-3
111 222 333
111 222 333
…
…
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: show the code. how you structured this 3 cols layout? using single row, 3 col table?

Comment: sorry, this question is 5 years old, I can't hardly remember, not to mention retrieving the code …